# node.js path too long windows 10

Tags: node.js, windows

I have been trying to install Node.js on my windows 10 machine. I get an error that says the path is too long and it shows a ridiculously long install path. I have researched it online and all I have found is suggestions that say to shorten the path to only abbreviations. How do I shorten these paths? I am using the installer and I do not get an option to edit this. Thank you.

Comment: Where are you trying to install it to?

Comment: This error may happen when trying to install node.js to a folder that either has a very long name or that is nested in many other folders. Try this: create a folder named "anything" in C:/ directory and then download and install node.js.

Comment: The default location it is trying to use is c:/program files/nodejs. I have been having issues like this with other software such as atom.io. My computer only started doing this recently.

Comment: I tried using a folder in the C directory and I got the same result.

Answer (score 2):

In Windows 10 anniversary edition (version 10.0.14939) and later you can set a registry value to enable paths longer than 260 characters.

Set the value of `1` to the following key:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\FileSystem\LongPathsEnabled
```

Also, if you happen to be using msysgit on Windows, you have to enable long file paths with the command:

```
git config --global core.longpaths true
```